# Receiving a typeerror and I can't start my expo react native app

Tags: react-native, expo

I can't start my expo react app.  Since I started developing the front end for this job, I've always added the --tunnel flag to start my expo app (npx expo start --tunnel), but now I am getting the error CommandError: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body').  If I remove the --tunnel flag, the project will build but then when I try to open it on the mobile app it just hangs.    I've searched my project for anything called body and commented it out and then tried to build but still no luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.